# Protractor: unknown error: [ng:btstrpd]

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a protractor setup which was working fine, but all of a sudden the tests are failing with the below error:

> Failed: unknown error: [ng:btstrpd]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/bts trpd?p0=document

[Full Error Log](http://pastebin.com/EKsik0eM)

The test is failing after opening the browser.Here is my test file

```
describe('PLM Login Page', function() {
  it('should login as the root ser', function() {

    browser.get('http://localhost:8080');

   // Fails from here
    element(by.linkText('Login')).click();

    element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('abc');
    element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('xyz');

    element(by.css('.btn-primary')).click();

    browser.driver.wait(protractor.until.elementIsVisible(element(by.linkText('Administrator'))));
  });
});
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you checked the error url that its pointing at and see if you are not making the same mistakes in your app? Thanks

Comment: Found ```os.name: 'Windows 7'``` and ```platform=XP``` in error log. Look like we have conflicts some where. More information may be needed, but first checkout which ```jasmine``` framework you are using (1 or 2). Check if you ChromeDriver compatible with your version of Chrome broser. ---- If things are complicating, just update base packages: ```protractor```, ```webdriver-manager``` then under your protractor config add this ```'framework': 'jasmine2',```

Comment: @GirishSortur Yes, I did checked the error url and made sure I am not making the mistake.